# Как в case использовать константы?

Tags: java, android, константа

Использую так:

```
public static int KOLVO_TC = 6;
public static int KOLVO_DA = 8;
int num;
num = KOLVO_DA;
..........................
switch (num){
    case KOLVO_TC: break;
    case KOLVO_DA: break;
    default: break;
}
```

Подчеркивает красным и всплывает "Constant expression required". Почему?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В качестве выражений для `case` необходимо использовать константы (причем *compile time constants* – их значение должно быть известно на момент компиляции программы).

Добавьте модификатор `final` к соответствующим полям.